# Cakephp search plugin search for foreign key

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the [friendsOfCake/search](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) plugin with CakePHP 3.8.

I have two tables likes this

**Strains**

```
Name    | user_id
-----------------
Strain1 | 1
Strain2 | 1
Strain3 | 2
```

**Users**

```
Name    | id
-----------------
Peter   | 1
Max     | 2
```

where `Strains.user_id` refers to the `id` columns in the `Users` table.
I want create a search mask where I can search for a user name and the result should be a list of strains which were created by this user. E.g. if I enter "Peter" the result should be "Strain1" and "Strain2".

According to https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/tree/master/docs#options I wrote the following code

StrainsTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->addBehavior('Search.Search');

    $this->searchManager()
        ->value ('user_id')
        ->like ('q', [ // q is the name of the input field in the view
            'fields' => ['Users.name'],
            'beforeProcess' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $args, \Search\Model\Filter\Base $filter) {
                $query->contain('Users');
            },
        ]);

    ...
}
```

StrainsController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $this->Strains
    ->find ('search', ['search' => $this->request->getQueryParams()]);
    debug($query);
    $this->set('strains', $this->paginate($query));
}
```

I get error message **Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Strains.q' in 'where clause'**

The created SQL-Query is this
`` SELECT Strains.name AS `Strains__name`, Strains.user_id AS `Strains__user_id`, Users.id AS `Users__id`, Users.name AS `Users__name` FROM strains Strains INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Strains.user_id) WHERE Strains.q like :c0 ``
where c0 is the value of q.

I'm happy for any kind of help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Which one is your question?

Comment: You need to use `callback` filter.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution: One has to map the input query `q` to the `Users.name` column using `field` (instead of `fields`) and the `fields` prob is used to specify the foreign key.

```
 $this->searchManager()
    ->value ('user_id')
    ->like ('q', [ // q is the name of the input field in the view
        'field' => ['Users.name']
        'fields' => ['user_id'],
        'beforeProcess' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $args, \Search\Model\Filter\Base $filter) {
            $query->contain('Users');
        },
    ]);
```

Comment: That's actually a typo in the docs, there is no `fields` option, the example should use `field` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->value('Users.email', [
        'field' => 'Users.email',
        'beforeProcess' => function (Query $query) {
            return $query->contain(['Users']);
        },
    ]);
```